# Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Can someone please explain Maximum Likelihood Estimation in very lay-man terms? I understand that the Likelihood function is obtained by multiplying all the probabilities in the distribution. Or if I am wrong, please correct.