# How to estimate unknown parameter via maximum likelihood?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

For instance, we observed $n$ tossing of a biased coin with probability of heads being $\theta$. How can I calculate this parameter via maximum likelihood? How can I derive the log-likelihood formula and the correct maximum likelihoo estimate of $\theta$?

Comment: Given $\theta$, what is the probability of seeing $x$ out of $n$ heads? So what is the likelihood function for $\theta$ given $x$ out of $n$ heads? How would you find a $\theta$ which maximises this likelihood?

Comment: I have tried to find a solution by myself. But do not know if it correct or not and do not know how tho derive the log-likelihood.

Comment: Give me moment, I am going to share it here.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45043/maximum-likelihood-estimation?rq=1) answer to a similar question useful.

Comment: We know that maximum likelihood is the value of the θ that is most well supported by the data. Let x be the number of heads and n be the number of tails, we get: L(θ,x) = θ^{x} (1-θ)^(n-x)
By applying derivative, we get: d/dθ(l(θ,x)) = x/θ - (n-x)/(1-θ),  And we get: (1-x/n)θ = (1-θ)x/n ; θ = x/n

Comment: The best would be to add your development to your question. Mathematic expressions can be formatted using [LaTeX](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I guess you meant $n-x$ tails.

Comment: I am editing it using LaTex format. We know that maximum likelihood is the value of the $\theta$ that is most well supported by the data. Let $x$ be the number of heads and $n$ be the number of tails, we get: $$L\left ( \theta ,x \right ) = \theta^x(1-\theta)^\left ( n-x\right ) $$ By applying derivative, we get: $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}L\left ( \theta,x \right ) = \frac{x}{\theta}-\frac{n-x}{1-\theta} $$ And, $$ \left ( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right )$$ So,$$\theta = \left ( 1-\theta \right )\frac{x}{n}; \theta = \frac{x}{n} $$

Comment: Again, the number of tails should be $n-x$, not $n$. Again, show your development in the question, not in comments. Also, the derivative you write is that of the *log*-likelihood $l(\theta,x)$, not the likelihood $L(\theta, x)$

Comment: Yes. I could discover it when the time for editing is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read your comment, where you write $L(\theta;x)=\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$. This is right for a *single* toss.

Let's say that head = 1 and tail = 0. If $\mathbf{x}_n$ is a set of $n$ tosses, the number of heads is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n\bar{x}$. The likelihood function is:
$$L(\theta;\mathbf{x}_n)\propto \theta^{\sum_ix_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_ix_i}=\theta^{n\bar{x}}(1-\theta)^{n-n\bar{x}}$$
The log-likelihood is:
$$\ell(\theta;\mathbf{x}_n)=n\bar{x}\ln\theta+(n-n\bar{x})\ln(1-\theta)$$
and:
$$\ell'(\theta;\mathbf{x}_n)=\frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta}-\frac{n-n\bar{x}}{1-\theta}=\frac{n\bar{x}-n\theta}{\theta(1-\theta)}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\hat\theta=\bar{x}$$